# go-chi web-app running in background

Tags: go

New to using the go-chi web app framework. After building (go build) a little test app, I am trying to run the compile go app as a daemon (as you would want for any real web-server). Sure, I can run it as a background unix process( # ./myapp & ), but I imagine there must be a more robust standard way to run the web app as a daemon. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Nope, using `&` is the typical method. There is no built-in support (that I know of) for running a Go application as a daemon.

Comment: The "robust standard way" is whatever your system provides, e.g. "systemd" or equivalent.

Comment: Using `&` is the typical method. Another common approach is fork-and-exit. Which you want depends on your needs. If you don't have a reason not to use `&`, though, just use that.

Comment: If you want to create a daemon, Unix daemon processes must detach from their controlling terminal and process group in order to do that you must fork your process twice after doing this and redirect all your outputs and logs into syslog you can go and create systemd script for your daemon management.